# Installing GD module for php7,Errors when configure php

Tags: php, gd, libpng

Installed zlib-1.2.7、libpng-1.5.9、freetype-2.6.4、jpeg-9 and libgd-2.1.0 in ubuntu successfully .

but when I configure for php7:

```
./configure --prefix=/alidata/server/php7 --enable-fpm --with-fpm-user=www --with-fpm-group=www --enable-mbstring --enable-pdo --enable-mysqlnd --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd  --with-openssl=/alidata/ssl --with-curl --with-zlib --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local --with-webp-dir --with-png-dir=/usr/local/lib --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/jpeg9 --with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/freetype --with-gd --enable-gd-native-ttf
```

I got : configure: error: Problem with libpng.(a|so) or libz.(a|so).

in config.log:

```
configure:33286: checking for png_write_image in -lpng
configure:33311: cc -o conftest -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib  -Wl,-rpath,/alidata/ssl/lib -L/alidata/ssl/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/jpeg9/lib -L/usr/local/jpeg9/lib -lz conftest.c -lpng  -ljpeg -lwebp -lcurl -lz -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lrt -lm -ldl -lnsl  -lxml2 -lcurl -lxml2 >&5
/usr/local/lib/libpng.so: undefined reference to `inflate'
/usr/local/lib/libpng.so: undefined reference to `crc32'
/usr/local/lib/libpng.so: undefined reference to `deflateReset'
/usr/local/lib/libpng.so: undefined reference to `deflate'
/usr/local/lib/libpng.so: undefined reference to `deflateInit2_'
/usr/local/lib/libpng.so: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/usr/local/lib/libpng.so: undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
/usr/local/lib/libpng.so: undefined reference to `trunc'
/usr/local/lib/libpng.so: undefined reference to `inflateInit_'
/usr/local/lib/libpng.so: undefined reference to `pow'
/usr/local/lib/libpng.so: undefined reference to `inflateReset'
/usr/local/lib/libpng.so: undefined reference to `floor'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:33311: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
```

Who can help me,thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

This options helps me with GD:

```
--with-gd=/usr/ --with-xpm-dir=/usr/ '--with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
```